# SelectPDF Tool to Convert HTML to PDF

Tags: html-to-pdf

I am trying to use SelectPDF.ConvertURL() on my local machine.  When I run this convert I get a PDF that has sizing issues with checkboxes.  Checkboxes are too large and not appearing as they appear in the HTML Page

BUT when I go to the http://selectpdf.com/demo/html-to-pdf-converter.aspx and give it the URL for my HTML test document it renders correctly.  URL for document is:  http://dev.TitleClose.com/BlankLoanEstimate.html

I am using the exact code that is given on the selectpdf.com/demo page.

Any ideas or advice is appreciated

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to set a different web page width. Try this sample:
http://selectpdf.com/demo/convert-url-to-pdf.aspx

For an A4 page, the corresponding web page width (to keep the font size) is 793px. More details about the content resizing here:
http://selectpdf.com/docs/ResizingContentDuringConversion.htm

Comment: How is this self promotion? It was a question asked specifically about SelectPdf and not about some other product. We specifically answered the question (5 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

add in your CSS @mediaprint the sames propierties that you have in you css. that's work for me.

@media print {
   …
}